# How to create a button which will generate email

Tags: html, forms, mailto, unsubscribe

I'm in the process of learning **html** and **css**. As a practical part of this process, I manually rewrite a mailing list using *"all the rules of beautiful code".*

How can I add a hyperlink to a word that will send an automatic e-mail to a specific address?

> Example - If you do not wish to continue receiving it, please (a
>   href="UNSUB") unsubscribe from this list; where "UNSUB" will
>   autogenerate email to delete@from_mailing.com with text "delete this
>   email from your list"

Comment: Well, you will need some kind of server side coding (java node, php) to send an email. This is not possible to be done only with client side javascript.

Comment: if you dont know server side programming, you can still do it using some 3rd party service like Mandrill, or Firebase Cloud Functions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site